# How do I look for a property and if its not commented then I update it, if its commented then uncomment, if not found, then write it

Tags: bash, unix, sed, grep, sudo

I want to search for `property` in a file through a bash script and if its found & if its commented then I want to uncomment it and want to update its value (the content after `=` sign) to `/path/to/file`. If its uncommented and the value is already `/path/to/file`, then do nothing. If its not found, then write it.

Here are some sample inputs:

`property= /path/to/file`

`property = /path/to/file`

`#property = /path/to/file`

`##property=/path/to/file`

Output:

`property = /path/to/file`

This is what I have so far but it doesn't work exactly:

`sed 's/#\?property *=.*/property=/path/to/file/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, With `sed` try following:

```
sed  -E '/^#+property/s/^#+//;/^property/ { /^property\s+=\s+\/path\/to\/file/! s/=.*/= \/path\/to\/file/}' /path/to/Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply enabling `-E` option of `sed` to enable ERE(extended regular expressions) then `-i` will do inplace update in Input_file. With command `/^#+property/` checking if line starts with #(1 or more occurrences) followed by property then substituting it  `s/^#+`(part of code) with `//` NULL in Input_file. Then checking 2nd condition if line starts with `property` and not having `/path/to/file` value in it then simply replace everything from `=` to till last with `= /path/to/file` in that line.

Above doesn't have `-i` option, in case you are Happy with results shown on terminal then use `sed -i` in above command.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231898/discussion-on-answer-by-ravindersingh13-how-do-i-look-for-a-property-and-if-its).